# Is there a way to save the checked/ticked items into an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, checkbox, nativescript

I have done a grid like this using the Checkbox plugin on the images,
[image]

The data-items have been flagged description, checked/not-checked booleans, id's etc.

This is my template code:

```
<StackLayout class="topbuttons">
<GridLayout columns="*,*" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="top">
    <Button class="btn btn-primary topbutton" text="Next" col="1" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>
</GridLayout>
```

more

```
<GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton  class="topgrid" loaded="loaded" >
<RadListView [items]="dataItems" >
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <GridLayout class="garmentpick">
                <Image [src]="item.image" (tap)="toggleCheck()" class="imageP" >
                 </Image>
                <CheckBox #CB1 checked="false" text="{{ item.id }}" ></CheckBox>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
    <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout ios:itemHeight="200" spanCount="2"></ListViewGridLayout>
</RadListView>
```

typescript

```
 export const DATAITEMS: Array<DataItem> = [
{    id: 5451545, 
     name: "Chefs Collection",
     description: "This is item description.",
     image: "~/images/chefscollection.jpg",
     selected: false 
},
];

export class Component implements OnInit {
@ViewChild("CB1") firstCheckBox: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(): void {

    this._dataItems = new ObservableArray(this.getDataItems());
}
getDataItems(): Array<DataItem> {
    return DATAITEMS;
}
toggleCheck() {
    console.log();
    this.firstCheckBox.nativeElement.toggle();
}
onTap() {
    const checkboxArray = new ObservableArray(this.items);
    this._dataItems.forEach((item) => {
       checkboxArray.push(this.firstCheckBox.nativeElement.text);
    });        
}
}
```

I want to save the clicked items into an array. I created an array, I am pushing the clicked items to the array in the ontap of a submit button, but using Array.push(item.id) only pushes just one item, or repeats it in that array. is there a way I can do this, I'm thinking about data-forms

Answer (score 2):

Your function is looping the array put it's pushing always the same element. You should do something like this:

```
onTap() {
    const checkboxArray = new ObservableArray(this.items);
        this._dataItems.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.selected){
          checkboxArray.push(item);
        }
    });        
}
```

in this way you push the item itself, not the real native element.
If you want to push the entire checkbox, you should have a look at `QuerySelector`.
Let me know if you want me to explain you further about QuerySelector.

Comment: I think the query selector might work. The above way doesn't put anything into the array because the _dataItem is defined by me and there everything is defined as  selected:false till it is ticked by someone.

Comment: The forEach((item)) is only browsing through static values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, by using `filter`, you can achieve what you want if I understand what you want:

```
checkboxArray = this._dataItems.filter((item) => item.selected);
```

Comment: Thanks man, but i want to filter the items that i have checked. if i could somehow first get those ticked items into some sort of array. this._dataItems has the items that i have hard coded which are false  till i check the boxes and submit